# python regex: how can I get the smallest substring from a certain word to the end of the text?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm analyzing a text and I'd like to extract the smallest substring starting from the occurrence of a certain word until the end of the text. My particular problem is that that word can be in several parts of my text.

I've tried the following:

```
pattern = re.compile('(word)(.*?)$', re.DOTALL)
result = re.search(pattern, MY_TEXT).group()
```

My problem is that this doesn't result in the smallest possible string being returned, but in the largest string found in the text (i.e: the first occurrence of `word` until the end of the text, instead of the last occurrence). I was sure that adding the `?` character after `.*` inside the second parenthesis would have solved the problem, but it didn't.

Example input:

```
text = "Pokémon is a media franchise managed by The Pokémon Company, a Japanese consortium between Nintendo, Game Freak, and Creatures.\nThe franchise began as Pokémon Red and Green (later released outside of Japan as Pokémon Red and Blue)."
word = 'Pokémon'
```

I'd expect my result to be the string: `Pokémon Red and Blue).`, but right now I'm getting the whole text as a result.

How can I get what I expect?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: example input and expected output?

Comment: To get your result, you could try `^.*(Pokémon .*)$` https://regex101.com/r/xFSx7A/1 The result is in group 1. See https://ideone.com/eCG6tc

Comment: Works perfectly in this example, but how could I get a more generalized result for my problem?

Comment: Do you mean dynamically add the word followed by a space or word boundary instead?

Comment: Your problem is that the lazy `?` doesn't count the second occurence once he met the first. You could add a lookahead to make that check. Something like: `'(word)(?!.*word).*$'`

Comment: @Luise Try it like this https://ideone.com/KEF8sc

Comment: @Tomerikoo it works exactly as I intended. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird, I understand the example you provide. However, I actually have several different texts such that using `group(1)` in `re.search` is not always going to work for this. Is there a way to use `group` so that it could always return the last occurrence among all those that match the regular expression?

Comment: The pattern will return only the last occurrence, which will be in group 1. Can you give an example text?

Comment: Happy to help! Do note that my pattern takes a few more steps than the other alternative suggested by @Thefourthbird. As it actually looks ahead from a curtain point on failure backtracks and starts all over again. The other option first goes to the end and then backtracks to the word (as beautifully explained in the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current pattern `(Pokémon)(.*?)$` has 2 capturing groups where it will only match the first occurrence of `word` because the second group follows by matching until the end of the string.

To get to the last word, you could use `.*Pokémon` as `.*` will first match until the end of the string and will backtrack until it can fit `Pokémon`.

Then the rest of the string will be matched by the following `.*` The value is in the first capturing group.

```
^.*(Pokémon .*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xFSx7A/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/KEF8sc)

To create a more dynamic pattern

```
text = "Pokémon is a media franchise managed by The Pokémon Company, a Japanese consortium between Nintendo, Game Freak, and Creatures.\nThe franchise began as Pokémon Red and Green (later released outside of Japan as Pokémon Red and Blue)."
word = "and"
pattern = r"^.*(" + re.escape(word) + ".*)$"
regex = re.compile(pattern, re.DOTALL)
result = re.search(regex, text).group(1)
print(result)
```

Result

> and Blue).

If the word can also be the last word in the sentence, you could assert what is on the right is not a non whitespace char `(?!\S)` using a negative lookahead.

```
^.*(Pokémon(?!\S).*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xFSx7A/2)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you wish to extract the last instance of `Pokémon` to the end of the input string, which this expression for instance

```
^.*(Pokémon.*)$
```

is likely to do so.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/QSAqZ4/1/)